# Problems with using free DBX driver in conjunction with TSQLConnection

Tags: delphi, database-connection, delphi-2009, firebird, dbx

I've downloaded free DBX driver from [here](http://sites.google.com/site/dbxfirebird/download). I have been trying to make it work for two days now, without success.

Here is the snapshot of my code:

```
unit uMainForm;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, SqlExpr, WideStrings, DBXDynalink, DB;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TMainForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var C: TSQLConnection;
begin
  C := TSQLConnection.Create(Self);
  try
    C.DriverName := 'FirebirdConnection';
    C.LibraryName := 'dbxfb4d12.dll';
    C.VendorLib := 'fbclient.dll';
    C.GetDriverFunc := 'getSQLDriverFIREBIRD';
    C.Params.Add('User_Name=SYSDBA');
    C.Params.Add('Password=masterkey');
    C.Params.Add('Database=C:\MyDB.fdb');
    C.Open;
    if C.Connected then
      ShowMessage('Connection is active')
  finally
    C.Free;
  end;
end;
```

After running the test I am receiving error:

> Unable to load fbclient.dll(ErrorCode 22). It may be missing from the
> system path.

I have required libraries in my application path, I have them even in the System32 path. I am not using dbxdrivers.ini and dbxconnections.ini.

So what is going on here? I have Delphi 2009 with latest updates.

Comment: Has anyone had success with that component? All I've ever heard about it are people with problems.

Comment: I would first try to make it work with the *.ini files, I've seen too many posts failing while trying not to include them. [Here's one](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=20783) such thread.

Comment: I did try it with the ini, trust me... But thanks for the tip. I've decided to give up and I've used a commercial solution from devart (currently on trial) which works without any problems.

Comment: @David - I did get it to work... finally. You can't wire anything up in the IDE... it all has to be done at runtime. I'd much rather use a driver that let's me build and see things in the IDE.

Comment: @cape There are lots of good drivers around so I don't understand the attraction of this one.

Comment: @David - The attraction - FREE!.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also try to put the fbclient.dll file in the same folder as the executable?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's necessary to have the fbclient.dll renamed to gds32.dll. It might do the trick.